# How to filter data from each filter value in Vuejs2?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to create filters with dynamic parameters for a datatable in vuejs2 . the grid data come from an Api rest in Laravel. I have a computed function which filters data and all filters are in different inputs. I have an object that has the values of the filters. i have the filter in a computed function but i am filtering with conditions. how can i filter for each filter value in each item property?, how can i make my code works for each item in the filters and every property of the data object without write all the conditions?

my data is :

```
data:function(){
gridFields:{gridfilters:{fname:'',fdescription:''}},
gridApiData: [
{
"id": 10057,
"name": "10053",
"description": "10053"
},
{
"id": 10058,
"name": "10054",
"description": "10054"
},
{
"id": 10059,
"name": "10055",
"description": "10055"
}
]
}
```

The fname and fdescription are the values of the input filters.

my computed function is :

```
computed:{
    //I need to filter the data array with all the filters from the filter object gridFields.gridfilter

    dataList:function(){
       var vm = this;
     return this.gridApiData.filter(function (item) {
        if(vm.gridFields.gridfilters.fname && !vm.gridFields.gridfilters.fdescription){
             return (item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(vm.gridFields.gridfilters.fname.toLowerCase()) !== -1);
         }
         if(!vm.gridFields.gridfilters.fname && vm.gridFields.gridfilters.fdescription){
           return (item.description.toLowerCase().indexOf(vm.gridFields.gridfilters.fdescription.toLowerCase()) !== -1);
         }
         if(vm.gridFields.gridfilters.fname && vm.gridFields.gridfilters.fdescription){
        return ((item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(vm.gridFields.gridfilters.fname.toLowerCase()) !== -1)
         && (item.description.toLowerCase().indexOf(vm.gridFields.gridfilters.fdescription.toLowerCase()) !== -1));
         }
         return item;});
    }
},
```

thank you for all the suggestions.

Comment: Use methods to filter. In condition with `v-show` or in combination with a `watcher` that recalculates the data that should be shown. But "filter... without write all the conditions" sounds impossible.

Comment: but if i want to use the component and receive as a parameter the conditions. Can i pass as a prop the conditions ?, can i pass the value of dataList as a prop? i try but is not working.

Comment: You can pass every object or array as prop to a component https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Props

I can only give you the hint to test your concept in an easy and debuggable way like a html file or this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/dr7fsp0w/1/ thats what i do. I think problems are easier to find when i can see them directly.